# How to UV unwrap a flat mesh in Blender

Tags: uv, unity

Just getting started with UV unwrapping and not sure how best to proceed. I have a 2d race track that I want to unwrap to begin creating a texture.

If I use standard unwrap with seams, I get the unwrap without any stretching but the UV map is then going to be quite hard to work with as it distorted to look at.

[image: Standards unwrap with seams]

Alternatively, to keep the straights and corners relatively sized to one another I unwrapped using project from View which obviously unwrapped in a way that's easier to manage but now a lot of the mesh has stretching.

[image: Unwrap project from view]

I'm new to UVs so I'm a little stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try "Follow active quad" unwrap

Answer (score 2):

1. *Unwrap* <kbd>U</kbd> one segment (polygon) of the road and use *UV Squares* -> To Grid by Shape, or make it rectangular manually
2. Select rest of the polygons and lastly this unwrapped segment so it becomes the *Active* quad
3. *Unwrap* -> *Follow Active Quads*

Then all the road mesh will be unwrapped based on that one quad mapping.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was that my mesh did not have scale set properly. Applying its scale then unwrapping again resulted in much less distortion.

Hopefully this is useful information for someone.